# Using "Tensorflow For Poets" example to train multiple objects in same image

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, object-detection-api

I want to use the [Tensorflow for Poets](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#0) example, but applied to multiple objects in the same image, without having to segment objects.

This example is easy to adapt to any dataset, I have found no example in this sense of multiple objects.

Just like the example below!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All that you have to do is just annotate the objects that you wish to train your model on. It does not matter even if you label multiple objects in an image. You can label objects using the [Labellmg tool](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg)

An sample on how to annotate multiple objects in an image is shown in the following link[image]

Hope this helps you out. Please let me know in case you have any other issue/if I have misunderstood your question